# How to add a .XLAM add-in to Microsoft Excel 2013 using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, excel-2013, excel-addins

I have written a vbscript to install an add-in to **Excel 2013**.

```
Dim oXL
Dim oAddin
Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oXL.Workbooks.Add
Set oAddin = oXL.AddIns.Add("C:\Apps\FMP.xlam", True)
oAddin.Installed = True
oXL.Quit
```

This works well with **Excel 2007** but does not install the add-in on **Excel 2013**.

With the help of the VBA reference for Excel 2013, I modified the script as follows :

```
Dim oXL
Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oXL.Workbooks.Add
oXL.Add("C:\Apps\FMP.xlam").Installed = True
oXL.Quit
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. What am I missing ?

Please help.

Comment: Can you describe what "doesn't work"? Do you get an error message? If so, please indicate what that says.  Have you checked obvious culprits like your security/trust center settings? Is this actually vbscript or is it just VBA in Excel?  Thanks.

Comment: I have used vbscript to implement VBA. No errors are displayed. The addin doesn't get installed, that is when excel is launched the addin isnt visible. The security and trust center settings are just fine. The addin does get installed with excel 2007 with similar settings.

Comment: Are you testing this script on a machine with both Office 2007 and 2010? If so, it's most likely launched 2007 version. Add `oXL.Visible = True` to check. You may need to run the 2010 exe file then GetObject.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim oXL
Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oXL.Workbooks.Add
oXL.AddIns.Add("C:\Temp\Fred_2010.xlam").Installed = True
oXL.Quit
```

Try this. It worked for me.